# How can I center align text with hyperlinks in it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink, alignment, textblock

How can I ***center align*** text with hyperlinks in it?

I need to have the some text below, and with the XAML I got it's currently not centered. In fact, Horizontal Alignment does not seem to have any effect. Hyperlinks are working fine, however.

This is inside a grid with 2 columns, and I need the ColumnSpan to be 2.

Thanks.

> "By clicking Sign In, you agree to our [HYPERLINK: Privacy Policy] and [HYPERLINK: Terms of Use.]"

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18px">
        <Run Text="By clicking Sign In, you agree to our " /> 
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://www.my-company-website.com/privacy-policy/" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            Privacy Policy
        </Hyperlink>
        <Run Text=" and "/>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://www.my-company-website.com/terms-and-conditions/" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            Terms of Use.
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `TextAlignment` property. Set this one to `Center`:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" ...
```

Comment: omg, I feel like a complete noob now. HorizontalAlignment is for the entire control, not the underlying text. Thanks for the help.